# Virtualbox access host localhost with proxy

Tags: .net, localhost, virtualbox

I have a windows 8.1 host machine, which has a virtualbox vm running windows 7 with IE9 for browser testing.

Many times before ive set up access to the host localhost:port from IIS express to be accessed by the guest VM via 10.0.2.2:port

**However in this case my employer uses a proxy to access the internet and our ethernet port has static DNS bound to it. I can ping the host ip but not the port (my application is asp.net MVC 5 app with windows auth) I receive error 400 bad request**

Network is configured like this:

GuestVM (NAT Adapter) -> Host OS software (proxifier - have tried with and without) -> ethernet (set DNS) -> work network -> internet

**To be clear**
I have internet access on the Guest.